# Displaying Modal Popup in Code Behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am showing ajaxcontrol tool kit ModalPopupExtender to show from code behind on button click.
On my button click I am uploading files and sending email, and after Emailing I am showing Modal Popup for few seconds then I am redirecting user to index page.

The problem I am having is that ModalPopup is only showing if I am not redirecting
This is my aspx code

```
<input type="btmodel" runat="server" style="display: none">
     <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="btmodel"
            PopupControlID="Panel1" PopupDragHandleControlID="PopupHeader" Drag="true" DropShadow="true"
            OkControlID="OkButton" CancelControlID="CancelButton" BackgroundCssClass="ModalPopupBG">
        </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" Style="display: none" runat="server">
            <div class="HellowWorldPopup">
                <div class="PopupHeader" id="PopupHeader">
                    Progress</div>
                <div class="PopupBody">
                    <p>
                       Processing.....</p>
                </div>
                <div class="Controls">
                    <input id="btnOkay" type="button" value="Ok" onclick="OkScript()" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>
```

and my button click code

```
  protected void btnupload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
  //File uploading 
  //Sending Email

   ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
   Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");//If I comment this line,then modal is showing
  }
```

I also tried with this before ModalPopupExtender1.Show(),but no luck

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is to make the redirection when the user close the popup, not when you're showing it. 
Write code to handle the "OnOkScript" or "OnCancelScript" and make the redirection there instead.

Answer (score 1):

Make yourself aware that in an ASP.NET (or any webserver/client browser environment), your server-side code will be executed till the end, THEN a result is sent to the client browser. It is not a back-and-forth kind of communication by design.